# Kafka Connect spamming rejoin

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've finally managed to setup Kafka Connect (using Kerberos, SSL and ACL) and deployed in a Kubernetes environment. It seemed work fine until, I believe, I tried to experiment with two workers. I did this by just changing the replication-factor in my k8s-spec to 2.
However this seem to have rendered my connector in a faulty state.

 Now each time i try to restart my k8s-deployment the worker seem to startup but then end up in a state spamming the log with:

```
[2020-04-20 13:49:02,882] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=orion_kafka_con] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-04-20 13:49:02,894] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=orion_kafka_con] Successfully joined group with generation 22981593 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-04-20 13:49:02,894] INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=1, leader='connect-1-ac35d22d-73a7-4d56-a42d-7e5904a52303', leaderUrl='http://<host>:8083/', offset=228, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
```

The error seem to occur disregarding of how many workers I run.

From the log you can tell that there seem to be an error (error=1) but Ive been unable to find out what that points to.
 I tried to resolve the issue by resetting the internal-topics (reducing retention time to 1s) but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I appreciate any help I can get.
Regards

**edit**: The logs are spewing out making (?) the REST-api unresponsive meaning I cant delete the started connector. Enabled DEBUG (with even more logs) but I cant seem to find anything wrong. No ERRORS, no WARNINGS.
**edit 2**: I managed to fix it but not resolve it. After resetting the kafka-connects internal topics (seems I wasnt giving the change of retention-time enough time to take affect) the problem eventually went away. I have no idea what caused the problem thou.

Comment: By the way, it might be worth enabling `DEBUG` log level for Kafka Connect.

Comment: Thats a good point @GiorgosMyrianthous, I will do that. Any idea what to look for?

Comment: How did you deploy it? Using Confluent Helm charts?

Comment: It is deployed through Jenkins and some custom-scripting in normal cases and for testing-purposes I sometimes deploy using Kubectl.